# Quiz in python with a external file for questions and answers

Tags: python, text-files

This is my code   not sure why im getting the error.  The error is "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"

```
def HistoryHard():
file = open('HistoryHard.txt','r')
for line in file:
    detail = line.split(',')
    print(detail[0])
    detail[1] = detail[1].strip('\n')
    Selection = input('1:Yeas\n2:No\n')
    if Selection == detail[1].strip(): #problem is this line
        print('correct')
    else:
        print('incorrect')
```

Comment: post the code in the question, everyone will complain about a screenshot

Comment: @David.P just paste in question with formatting problems if you can't figure it out, somebody else can edit it

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on your print(detail[1].strip('\n')) for starters.

Comment: It seems you have fixed your issue by using 1 instead of '1', right? I simulated your code and had no error at all. Only got that error when I change 1 to '1'. `if Selection == detail['1'].strip(): #problem is this line`